# nodemon not found in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I have a problem: nodemon does not run off the npm script (e.g. `npm start`),
but if nodemon is called on the command line outside the npm script, nodemon runs as normal.

```
$ nodemon server.js
14 Feb 22:59:51 - [nodemon] v1.3.7
14 Feb 22:59:51 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
14 Feb 22:59:51 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
14 Feb 22:59:51 - [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
```

How it is called in npm script:

```
package.json

{
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  }
}
```

When npm start script is run:

```
$ npm start
> aaa@0.0.1 start /home/akul/Documents/aaa
> nodemon server.js

sh: 1: nodemon: not found

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-45-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/home/akul/npm-global/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! aaa@0.0.1 start: `nodemon server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the aaa@0.0.1 start script 'nodemon server.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the aaa package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     nodemon server.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls aaa
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/akul/Documents/aaa/npm-debug.log
```

I've been looking for a solution, but have not found one.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can resolve this problem by adding `nodemon` to your `package.json`:

```
npm install nodemon --save-dev
```

The problem happens when `nodemon` does not exist in `/node_modules/.bin`.

Added `--save-dev` since it's required during development only.

Comment: npm WARN prefer global nodemon@1.3.7 should be installed with -g
but now successfully, thank you
so nodemon that in a global directory of unused :D

Comment: I also got same problem. now resolve for this command - npm install nodemon --save

Comment: Don't install nodemon with flag --save because nodemon uses only for development. Use ``-g`` or ``--save-dev`` flag

Answer (score 47):

1. Try to check installed global packages:

   `npm list -g --depth=0`
2. If you will not find `nodemon`, - install it with flag `-g` or `--save-dev`:

   `npm install nodemon --save-dev` OR `npm install nodemon -g`

**Don't install `nodemon` with flag `--save`, because `nodemon` uses only for `development`.**

Comment: npm install -g nodemon

Answer (score 37):

under your current project directory, run

```
npm install nodemon --save //save in package.json so that the following code cam find your nodemon
```

then under "scripts" in your *package.json* file, add "start": "nodemon app.js" (or whatever your entry point is) 
so it looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
}
```

and then run

```
npm start
```

That avoids complicate PATH settings and it works on my mac
hope can help you ;)

Comment: Don't install nodemon with flag --save because nodemon uses only for development. Use -g or --save-dev

Answer (score 30):

Install `nodemon` globally using following command. It works on my computer, and I'm sure it will work on your system also.

```
npm install nodemon -g --save
```

Sometimes you should have the permission to install it globally. It can be easily done by using following command.

1. In LINUX UBUNTU:
   `sudo npm install nodemon -g --save`
2. In Fedora:

   a) `su`
   b)`npm install nodemon -g --save`

Answer (score 11):

Try to install nodemon globally.

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Here's how I fixed it :

When I installed nodemon using : **`npm install nodemon -g --save`** , my path for the global npm packages was not present in the PATH variable .

**If you just add it to the $PATH variable it will get fixed.**

Edit the **`~/.bashrc`** file in your home folder and add this line :-

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/npm
```

**Here "npm" is the path to my global npm packages . Replace it with the global path in your system**

Comment: path should be npm bin location 
This works  export `PATH=$PATH:~/npm/bin`

Answer (score 4):

heroku runs in a production environment by default so it does not install the dev dependencies.

if you don't want to reinstall nodemon as a dependency which I think shouldn't because its right place is in devDependencies not in dependencies.

instead, you can create two npm script to avoid this error by running nodemon only in your localhost like that:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon --watch"
},
```

and when you want to run the project locally just run in your terminal `npm run start:dev` and it will load app.js by nodemon.

while in heroku `npm start` runs by default and load app.js from a normal node command and you get rid of that error.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it. This was me error:

```
npm install -g nodemon
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rayani00/.npm/_logs/2022-01-03T17_50_15_842Z-debug.log
(base) rayani00@rayani00:~/Bureau/my-express-server$ npm cache clear --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
```

To solve it i just aded a sudo for the nodemon installation :

1. sudo npm install -g nodemon
2. nodemon server.js

That worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

You have to simply installed it globally.
    npm install -g nodemon

Comment: This also worked for me.  Then to start  - #nodemon ./path/to/startfile

Answer (score 2):

This solution had worked for me:

I assume that you have installed nodemon globally. If it's done follow this steps:

open your .bash_profile file:

```
nano .bash_profile
```

past this to add a new alias in your bash profile:

```
alias nodemon='~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js'
```

Now you can use nodemon command anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

My nodemon vanished after installing babel (why?).

Tried a lot of stuff.
Here is how I solved it:

```
sudo npm i -g nodemon
```

Just reinstall it with sudo. Yeah.

Comment: noice solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo npm install nodemon -g --save
```

Finally this worked for me. I hope this must work for others too

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio Code editor with Windows Sub-system for Linux, i.e, WSL mode:

```
sudo npm install nodemon -g
```

for global use of nodemon.

Answer (score 1):

NPM is used to manage packages and download them. However, NPX must be used as the tool to execute Node Packages

Try using NPX nodemon ...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me ...

Install nodemon as a local dev dependency

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

Add script to your application package.json to start the application.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon app.js"
},
```

Start nodemon with `npm start`

```
$ npm start

> node-rest-demo@1.0.0 start node-rest-demo
> nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 1.19.4 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs` [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.* [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json [nodemon] starting `node app.js` Starting server ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, but then checked .npmrc file and there was incorrect password in that that caused the connection failure and there fore yarn --verbose returned Bad request error. After correcting the password, the packages were added successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very easy solution.
Simply delete the npm and npm cache folder from your pc.
Reinstall it again, but the mistake that many of us make is not installing npm globally.So:

```
npm i -g npm
```

And then, install nodemon globally:

```
npm i -g nodemon
```

Now,nodemon works globally, even without using the command:

```
npx nodemon <yourfilename>.js
```

Answer (score 1):

npx nodemon (app.js) worked for me and nodemon (app.js) did not.

I updated node.js to the latest version and now both are working.

Comment: This has nothing to do with an update of node. `nodemon` installed locally goes in `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon`. So you can  `npx` to execute npm package binaries, or you can install `nodemon` globally (using `-g`) as stated in multiple other answers.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I had installed nodemon globally but still did not work for me. It was only until node.js was updated that it began working. Not sure how, but that's how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and even after I have used the command `npm install nodemon --save` in my application, I still had problem with nodemon.

I just resolved after I installed nodemon globally, using the command:`npm install nodemon -g`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem otherwise was just working fine a day ago.
Very simple fix
first check if nodemon exists on your system globally or not

> To check

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

If you don't see then install 
it `npm install -g nodemon` (g stands for globally)

If you see it still doesn't work then you need to configure environment variable
**I use Windows OS.** On Windows navigate to

```
Control panel>System>Advanced System Settings>Environment Variables>double-click on PATH
```

Now check if you have this PATH `C:\Users\yourUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm`

If not, you will see some existing paths, just append to it separating with semicolon. That's it! **Worked for me.** 
For me node was installed in C:..\Roaming\npm and for you if the PATH is different, you will put in whatever applcable.

Comment: I some how lost the entry in my PATH. Not sure how, but your suggestion fixed it. Thanks

Comment: My pleasure!! Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

First install nodemon to  your working folder by

```
npm install nodemon
```

Add the path of nodemon to the **path variable of Environment Variable of System environment**.
In my case the path of nodemon was.

```
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Internship Project\schema\node_modules\.bin
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can always reinstall Node.js. When I had this problem, I couldn't fix it, but all I did was update the current version of Node. You can update it with this link: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add how I fixed this issue, as I had to do a bit of mix and match from a few different solutions. For reference this is for a Windows 10 PC, nodemon had worked perfectly for months and then suddenly the command was not found unless run locally with npx. 
Here were my steps -

1. Check to see if it is installed globally by running `npm list -g
   --depth=0`, in my case it was installed, so to start fresh...
2. I ran `npm uninstall -g nodemon`
3. Next, I reinstalled using `npm install -g --force nodemon --save-dev` (it might be recommended to try running `npm install -g nodemon --save-dev` first, go through the rest of the steps, and if it doesn't work go through steps 2 & 3 again using --force).
4. Then I checked where my npm folder was located with the command `npm config get prefix`, which in my case was located at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
5. I modified my PATH variable to add both that file path and a second entry with \bin appended to it (I am not sure which one is actually needed as some people have needed just the root npm folder and others have needed bin, it was easy enough to simply add both)
6. Finally, I followed similar directions to what Natesh recommended on this entry, however, with Windows, the .bashrc file doesn't automatically exist, so you need to create one in your ~ directory. I also needed to slightly alter how the export was written to be `export PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm;` (Obviously replace "username" with whatever your username is, or whatever the file path was that was retrieved in step 4)

I hope this helps anyone who has been struggling with this issue for as long as I have!

Answer (score 0):

--save, -g and changing package.json scripts did not work for me. Here's what did: running `npm start` (or using `npx nodemon`) within the command line. I use visual studio code terminal.
When it is successful you will see this message:
 
[nodemon] 1.18.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case nodemon needed to be installed globally:

```
npm i nodemon -g --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to list global packages using  `npm list -g --depth=0`, but couldn't find nodemon.
Hence, tried installing it using global flag.
`sudo npm install nodemon -g`
This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for Windows,

Open Command Prompt.
type `npm i -g nodemon --save` 
"--save" is to save the addition of this node package in your project's package.json file

Answer (score 0):

I my case:

```
npm install nodemon
```

With out any flags etc.

Answer (score 0):

for linux try

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

for windows 
open powershell or cmd as administration

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue while deploying on Heroku.
The problem is on Heroku the don't include the devDependencies on its own.
To fix this issue, simply run the command in the terminal:

> **heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false**

Make sure to include nodemon in your devDependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
```

### Incase your error is not in Heroku

I would suggest uninstalling nodemon and then reinstalling it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Or try changing the script

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon fileName.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon fileName.js"
 }
```

Hope it would help :)

Answer (score 0):

nodemon --watch contracts --exec "truffle compile" contracts/Presale.sol