# Babel config in a MERN app

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, babeljs

I have given up at trying to learn rails. I'm now focusing my energy on trying to get started with node, using the MERN stack. I have done both Stephen Grider and Andrew Mead's udemy course as well as all of the code school js courses. I'm afraid I'm not off to a promising start.

I'm stuck at getting my import statements to work. So far, I have tried to import files. For that I need babel. My package.json has:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test/**/*-test.js --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive",
    "start": "nodemon -w server.js server.js  --source-maps"
  },
  "author": "Ol",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "caniuse-api": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "material-ui": "^0.18.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-promise": "^1.1.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-form": "^6.7.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.8.2",
    "mocha": "^3.3.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.5.1",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

My .babelrc has:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
}
```

My server.js has:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import SourceMapSupport from 'source-map-support';


SourceMapSupport.install(); //to get line numbers with file refs rather than compiled code line numbers


// const app = express();

app.use(express.static('open'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on 3000');
});
```

My webpack.config.js has:

```
module :{
    rules:[{
      // use : 'babel-loader',
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query :{
        presets:['react','es2015']
        // ,'es2017'
      },
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
    }]
```

When I try to use npm start, I get an error with my import statements. It says:

```
{ import express from 'express';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can anyone give me a clue on how to get babel setup to work with a node app. I noticed that even when I run npm install in my console, I don't get a node_modules folder in my app. I used yarn to add dependencies to package.json, but don't seem to have the ability to generate an node_modules folder.

**Next attempt**

I then tried npm init and then npm upgrade (even though I use yarn for adding modules).

The output of npm upgrade is below, but I still don't end up with a node modules folder. I think the reason babel isn't working to recognise my import statements is because I don't have the module in my app. Does anyone know how to get a node modules file to be created in the setup? I thought that happened automatically.

```
npm update
npm WARN deprecated isarray@2.0.1: Just use Array.isArray directly

> uws@0.14.5 install /Users/mlc/may/node_modules/uws
> node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0

- ms@0.7.3 node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ms
- debug@2.6.4 node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/debug
- ms@0.7.3 node_modules/finalhandler/node_modules/ms
- react-addons-create-fragment@15.5.4 node_modules/react-addons-create-fragment
- react-addons-transition-group@15.5.2 node_modules/react-addons-transition-group
- ms@0.7.3 node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ms
- debug@2.6.4 node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/debug
- camelcase@1.2.1 node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/camelcase
- cliui@2.1.0 node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/cliui
cr@1.0.0 /Users/mlc/may
├── axios@0.16.2 
├── body-parser@1.17.2 
├── express@4.15.3 
├── material-ui@0.18.2 
├── mocha@3.4.2 
├── react-promise@1.1.3 
├── react-redux@5.0.5 
├── socket.io@2.0.2 
└── webpack@2.6.1
```

Comment: Unexpected token import , its import express from 'express' ;

Comment: I don't understand your point @Kasiriveni - the line in my code is: import express from 'express';

Answer (score 0):

Use `presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]`.

If you want to run your server.js with export and import, add `babel-node`.

**package.json**

```
...
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel-node server.js",
"dev": "nodemon server.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,react,stage-2"
...
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
    },
    "development": {
      "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a babelrc file - it's above.  I tried adding stage 2 to it, but I get the same error

Comment: I tried your suggestion, i get an error that says: Hello there undefined                            │
|          You tried to install babel-node. This is not babel-node           │
|               You should npm install -g babel-cli instead  .               │
|    I took this module to prevent somebody from pushing malicious code.     │
|                    Be careful out there, undefined!

Comment: You use `nodemon`, maybe try this `nodemon server.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,react,stage-2`

Comment: Where would you suggest I try writing that? I am trying to use nodemon but I can't get it to work.  -bash: nodemon: command not found

Comment: Install nodemon: `npm install nodemon -g`

Comment: success Saved 1 new dependency.
└─ nodemon@1.11.0
✨  Done in 17.70s.
may$ nodemon server.js
-bash: nodemon: command not found

Comment: `-g` installs the package globally. Maybe restart your terminal.

Comment: Try to add it locally `npm install nodemon --save`

Comment: i tried both local and global. i get the same bash error

Comment: Ok. Please try it without `nodemon` (first line in my package.json code). It's only for development to restart your server and it is not necessary to solve your import/export problem. A thread about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517494/nodemon-not-found-in-npm

Comment: I've tried node and also get an error pointing to the import statement